# What does android Wifi ScanResult.level value means?

Tags: android, signals, wifi

I'm trying to make an app that can measure of a detected Wifi signal strength.

i'm using this code

```
for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
   ScanResult scanresult = wifi.getScanResults().get(i);
   int rssi = scanresult.level;
}
```

what i want to ask is, since the result is always negative (-67, -88, -90, etc), what is the value means? is it the loss, or is it the received signal level?

thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the documentation for `level`:

> The detected signal level in dBm. At least those are the units used by the TI driver.

Quoting [an old `alt.internet.wireless` post](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/9782-43-read-signal-strength#8171161):

> The reason you see negative values is that you're representing small
>   but positive numbers, on a logarithmic scale. In logarithms, the value
>   indicated represents an exponent... for example, under a log 10 scale,
>   a value of -2 represents 10 to the -2 power, which equals 0.01.
>   Likewise, a negative dBm means that you're applying a negative
>   exponent in your power calculations; 0 dBm equals 1 mW of power, so
>   -10 dBm equates to 0.1 mW, -20 dBm equates to 0.01 mW, and so forth.
>   It's a lot easier, and more useful in some calculations, to describe a
>   weak signal as -100 dBm as opposed to 0.0000000001 mW.

Comment: @arranda: That would be how I would interpret it, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use calculateSignalLevel method form WifiManager like this:

```
int range = 5; //the range of integers you want to match the level (in this case it will be from 0 to 4)

int signalStrength = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi, range);
```

You can visit  [this source.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#calculateSignalLevel(int,%20int))

Answer (score 0):

-49, -47 means that the signal is very good like documentations based on dBm say.